# How to get TypeTag from java.lang.Class

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I have a requirement where I need to send from java or scala class a 3rd party class name to an API which I am writing in scala . From that (3rd party) class name I have to instantiate its object (**which might have a parameterized constructor as well**) and call its corresponding methods . I made attempts but I am not very well clear with the complete reflection working so it looks like this for now:

External (java/scala) class accessing the API :

```
class AnyRandomClass{

MyAPI api = new API();
api.getThirPartyObject(ThirdPartyClassName);
}
```

Here is the attempt to write the scala API :

```
package mypckg

import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class MyAPI{
def getThirdPartyObject ={
   val u = universe
   val m = u.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
   //throws error : type staticClass is not a member of mypckg.MyAPI.u.Mirror
   m.runtimeClass(typeOf[m.staticClass(clazz.getName).selfType].typeSymbol.asClass)
}

}
```

Please help me understand where am I going wrong here , also whats the correct and better way to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a requirement where I need to send from java or scala class a 3rd party class name to an API which I am writing in scala . From that (3rd party) class name I have to instantiate its object (which might have a parameterized constructor as well) and call its corresponding methods

You don't need a `TypeTag` for this. Just using Java reflection:

```
val constructors = clazz.getConstructors 
// see also getConstructor, getDeclaredConstructors, and getDeclaredConstructor
val constructor = // select the constructor you need
constructor.newInstance(parameters)
// etc
```

If you do need to use Scala reflection, `ClassTag` should be enough and trivial to get:

```
ClassTag(clazz)
```